# AngularJS Directive Dynamically Change Attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, masking

I have a bank selector. When the user change the bank, the mask of the bank's account should dynamically change.

I made a directive to make this dynamic change. I'm inspecting the DOM and the mask is being updated, but it's not working, the mask remains as the first one.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <select ng-model="bankInfo.bank" ng-options="bank.name for bank in banks"></select>
    <input bank-mask="bankInfo" type="text" ng-model="bankInfo.account">
</fieldset>
```

BankMask Directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        bankInfo: '=bankMask'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch('bankInfo.bank.code', function(newBankCode, oldBankCode) {
            if (oldBankCode !== newBankCode) {
                element.attr('mask', getMask(newBankCode));
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Try calling `scope.$apply()` after the line with `$compile`

Comment: Is this roughly what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/5qpLcmvf/1/

Comment: @Fissio I can't do that, since I'm inside $scope.$watch =/

Comment: @DavidBarker thank you for the help but no.. I want to change an attribute (mask) value. Something like this: <input mask="999"> to this: <input mask="99999999">, dynamically.

Comment: Can you add the code that you have in the controller as well?